# Built-in functions on the LHS won't pattern-match

Tags: pattern-matching, built-in-symbols

I have this pattern-matching problem:

`F[X_,myminus[X_]]:=0`

`F[1,myminus[1]]`

Works.

`G[X_,-X_]:=0`

`G[1,-1]`

Oops. (Doesn't match with `Minus` either.)

I simply use

`H[X_,Y_]]:=0/;X==-Y`

`H[1,-1]`

which also leaves no question about

`H[-1,1]`

but there sure must be a way to use only one LHS variable and this would speed up the pattern matching (uhm, does it really)?

EDIT: I should emphasize that a) speed is the thing that matters most and b) technically my `X_` variable can only take three values, `{0,1,-1}`, and even these values are meaningless, so I could as well call them `{a,b,c}`, and only `F[a,b]` and `F[b,a]` shall trigger the rule. My own alternative idea is using the first approach and defining `myminus[a]=b,myminus[b]=a` which also may shorten my other rules.

Comment: The problem is that "-X_" is interpreted as a product of -1 times X. "-1" on the other hand is a number, no product implied.  You could try a condition on the LHS: G[X_,Y_]; X==-Y:=0

Answer (score 1):

You could post-process the definitions:

```
ClearAll[FixMinusPattern];

SetAttributes[FixMinusPattern, HoldAll];

FixMinusPattern[fn_] := 
 DownValues[fn] = 
  Quiet@ReplaceAll[DownValues[fn], 
    HoldPattern[
      Verbatim[HoldPattern][
       fn[PatternSequence[otherArgs1___, Verbatim[Pattern][a_, type_],
          otherArgs2___, -1*Verbatim[Pattern][a_, type_], 
         otherArgs3___]]]] :> 
     Module[{Arg2}, 
      HoldPattern[
       Condition[
        fn[otherArgs1, Pattern[a, type], otherArgs2, 
         Pattern[Arg2, type], otherArgs3], a == -Arg2]]]]
```

### Examples

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, -x_] := {x};

{f[1, 1], f[1, -1]}
(*Out: {f[1, 1], f[1, -1]} *)

FixMinusPattern[f];

{f[1, 1], f[1, -1]}
(*Out: {f[1, 1], {1}} *)
```

You could define other arguments:

```
ClearAll[g];
g[a_, c_, b_, -c_] := {a, b, c};

{g[1, 2, 3, 2], g[1, 2, 3, -2]}
(*Out: {g[1, 2, 3, 2], g[1, 2, 3, -2]} *)

FixMinusPattern[g];

{g[1, 2, 3, 2], g[1, 2, 3, -2]}
(*Out: {g[1, 2, 3, 2], {1, 3, 2}} *)
```

Notes:

- It'll manipulate function's `DownValues` **in-place**.
- The normal pattern and minus one should have the same name and type.
- The minus pattern should appear after the normal one, which can be easily fixed. (add another replace rule with `Verbatim` and `-1*Verbatim` reversed)
- It uses `Condition[..., a == -b]`, you could change it easily too.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly pointless way of solving the problem with a single variable...

```
G[X : Repeated[_, {2}] /; {X} . {1, 1} == 0] := 0

G[4, -4]
(* 0 *)
```